# Correct use of jQuery.fn.doOnce()

Tags: jquery, performance

One optimization tip on jQuery states [Don’t Act on Absent Elements](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/dont-act-on-absent-elements/) but the given sample there isn't very clear on its use.

So for example to improve performance of

```
$('.elem').width(123).height(321);
```

in case there's no elem class, is the following the right choice?

```
$('.elem').doOnce(function(){ $(this).width(123).height(321)});
```

Also: is this minor possible speed optimization (when the element doesn't exist) worth the additional code written for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would be the right choice:

```
$('.elem').doOnce(function(){
 $(this).width(123).height(321)
});
```

But remember, you have to define the "doOnce" function beforehand, so for it to work it would have to be:

```
jQuery.fn.doOnce = function( func ) {

    this.length && func.apply( this );

    return this;

}

$('.elem').doOnce(function(){
     $(this).width(123).height(321)
    });
```

Regarding if the code is worth the performance gain, I don't know, but if it is in the documentation there probably is something to it, especially on larger pieces of code. Note that in the documentation there is this snippet:

```
// Bad: This runs three functions before it
// realizes there's nothing in the selection
$( "#nosuchthing" ).slideUp();
```

In that little snippet we have 3 functions already, imagine in larger code how many it would be, especially since many of the built-in jQuery functions are actually running more than one function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the question? Please see [ask].

Comment: Hi adam, thanks! but this wasn't a question, I was trying to post a reply, did I do something wrong?

Comment: My fault... I was reviewing posts and didnt get it was an answer! Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

this is some thing related to Don’t Act on Absent Elements.
Qjuery can't detect if the element is exist or not.
It is worth if you design your own huge plugin which has a huge functionality or some other HTTP request dependencies.
Imagine your plugin needs a configuration before doing the original effect this will cause time and resources cast. At end you will never use them just because the element is not exist already.
Hope that answer find your well.

Comment: This isn't answering the question, just repeating part of the question

Answer (score -1):

jQuery won't tell you if you're trying to run a whole lot of code on an empty selection – it will proceed as though nothing's wrong. It's up to you to verify that your selection contains some elements

https://learn.jquery.com/performance/dont-act-on-absent-elements/

Comment: This isn't an answer, just repeating a part of the question with the same link included in it...